# All of my products are unique, and I don't need them to stay in catalogue, once they are sold

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i am creating shopping site with woocommerce, using virtual and downloadable product
i want to be deleted after purchase it and no one can purchase the same product again

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just setting the stock count of each item to 1? You can then enable **Hide Out of Stock Items from the Catalog** in your WooCommerce settings.

It is possible to do with code but this is a more elegant solution as you may want to have the product data available when looking at orders received, etc.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code for digital download, where can i add the code to be download it once

```
<?php
```

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

/**
 * Download handler.
 *
 * Handle digital downloads.
 *
 * @class       WC_Download_Handler
 * @version     2.2.0
 * @package     WooCommerce/Classes
 * @category    Class
 * @author      WooThemes
 */
class WC_Download_Handler {

```
/**
 * Hook in methods.
 */
public static function init() {
    if ( isset( $_GET['download_file'] ) && isset( $_GET['order'] ) && isset( $_GET['email'] ) ) {
        add_action( 'init', array( __CLASS__, 'download_product' ) );
    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_download_file_redirect', array( __CLASS__, 'download_file_redirect' ), 10, 2 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_download_file_xsendfile', array( __CLASS__, 'download_file_xsendfile' ), 10, 2 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_download_file_force', array( __CLASS__, 'download_file_force' ), 10, 2 );
}

/**
 * Check if we need to download a file and check validity.
 */
public static function download_product() {
    $product_id    = absint( $_GET['download_file'] );
    $_product      = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    $download_data = self::get_download_data( array(
        'product_id'  => $product_id,
        'order_key'   => wc_clean( $_GET['order'] ),
        'email'       => sanitize_email( str_replace( ' ', '+', $_GET['email'] ) ),
        'download_id' => wc_clean( isset( $_GET['key'] ) ? preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $_GET['key'] ) : '' )
    ) );

    if ( $_product && $download_data ) {
        self::check_current_user_can_download( $download_data );

        do_action( 'woocommerce_download_product', $download_data->user_email, $download_data->order_key, $download_data->product_id, $download_data->user_id, $download_data->download_id, $download_data->order_id );

        self::count_download( $download_data );
        self::download( $_product->get_file_download_path( $download_data->download_id ), $download_data->product_id );
    } else {
        self::download_error( __( 'Invalid download link.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
}

/**
 * Get a download from the database.
 *
 * @param  array  $args Contains email, order key, product id and download id
 * @return object
 * @access private
 */
private static function get_download_data( $args = array() ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions ";
    $query .= "WHERE user_email = %s ";
    $query .= "AND order_key = %s ";
    $query .= "AND product_id = %s ";

    if ( $args['download_id'] ) {
        $query .= "AND download_id = %s ";
    }

    return $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare( $query, array( $args['email'], $args['order_key'], $args['product_id'], $args['download_id'] ) ) );
}

/**
 * Perform checks to see if the current user can download the file.
 * @param  object $download_data
 * @access private
 */
private static function check_current_user_can_download( $download_data ) {
    self::check_order_is_valid( $download_data );
    self::check_downloads_remaining( $download_data );
    self::check_download_expiry( $download_data );
    self::check_download_login_required( $download_data );
}

/**
 * Check if an order is valid for downloading from.
 * @param  array $download_data
 * @access private
 */
private static function check_order_is_valid( $download_data ) {
    if ( $download_data->order_id && ( $order = wc_get_order( $download_data->order_id ) ) && ! $order->is_download_permitted() ) {
        self::download_error( __( 'Invalid order.', 'woocommerce' ), '', 403 );
    }
}

/**
 * Check if there are downloads remaining.
 * @param  array $download_data
 * @access private
 */
private static function check_downloads_remaining( $download_data ) {
    if ( '0' == $download_data->downloads_remaining  ) {
        self::download_error( __( 'Sorry, you have reached your download limit for this file', 'woocommerce' ), '', 403 );
    }
}

/**
 * Check if the download has expired.
 * @param  array $download_data
 * @access private
 */
private static function check_download_expiry( $download_data ) {
    if ( $download_data->access_expires > 0 && strtotime( $download_data->access_expires ) < strtotime( 'midnight', current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) ) {
        self::download_error( __( 'Sorry, this download has expired', 'woocommerce' ), '', 403 );
    }
}

/**
 * Check if a download requires the user to login first.
 * @param  array $download_data
 * @access private
 */
private static function check_download_login_required( $download_data ) {
    if ( $download_data->user_id && 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_downloads_require_login' ) ) {
        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
            if ( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) ) {
                wp_safe_redirect( add_query_arg( 'wc_error', urlencode( __( 'You must be logged in to download files.', 'woocommerce' ) ), wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ) );
                exit;
            } else {
                self::download_error( __( 'You must be logged in to download files.', 'woocommerce' ) . ' <a href="' . esc_url( wp_login_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ) ) . '" class="wc-forward">' . __( 'Login', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>', __( 'Log in to Download Files', 'woocommerce' ), 403 );
            }
        } elseif ( ! current_user_can( 'download_file', $download_data ) ) {
            self::download_error( __( 'This is not your download link.', 'woocommerce' ), '', 403 );
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Log the download + increase counts.
 * @param object $download_data
 */
public static function count_download( $download_data ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $wpdb->update(
        $wpdb->prefix . 'woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions',
        array(
            'download_count'      => $download_data->download_count + 1,
            'downloads_remaining' => $download_data->downloads_remaining > 0 ? $download_data->downloads_remaining - 1 : $download_data->downloads_remaining,
        ),
        array(
            'permission_id' => absint( $download_data->permission_id ),
        ),
        array( '%d', '%s' ),
        array( '%d' )
    );
}

/**
 * Download a file - hook into init function.
 * @param string $file_path URL to file
 * @param integer $product_id of the product being downloaded
 */
public static function download( $file_path, $product_id ) {
    if ( ! $file_path ) {
        self::download_error( __( 'No file defined', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }

    $filename = basename( $file_path );

    if ( strstr( $filename, '?' ) ) {
        $filename = current( explode( '?', $filename ) );
    }

    $filename             = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_file_download_filename', $filename, $product_id );
    $file_download_method = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_file_download_method', get_option( 'woocommerce_file_download_method', 'force' ), $product_id );

    // Add action to prevent issues in IE
    add_action( 'nocache_headers', array( __CLASS__, 'ie_nocache_headers_fix' ) );

    // Trigger download via one of the methods
    do_action( 'woocommerce_download_file_' . $file_download_method, $file_path, $filename );
}

/**
 * Redirect to a file to start the download.
 * @param  string $file_path
 * @param  string $filename
 */
public static function download_file_redirect( $file_path, $filename = '' ) {
    header( 'Location: ' . $file_path );
    exit;
}

/**
 * Parse file path and see if its remote or local.
 * @param  string $file_path
 * @return array
 */
public static function parse_file_path( $file_path ) {
    $wp_uploads     = wp_upload_dir();
    $wp_uploads_dir = $wp_uploads['basedir'];
    $wp_uploads_url = $wp_uploads['baseurl'];

    // Replace uploads dir, site url etc with absolute counterparts if we can
    $replacements = array(
        $wp_uploads_url                  => $wp_uploads_dir,
        network_site_url( '/', 'https' ) => ABSPATH,
        network_site_url( '/', 'http' )  => ABSPATH,
        site_url( '/', 'https' )         => ABSPATH,
        site_url( '/', 'http' )          => ABSPATH
    );

    $file_path        = str_replace( array_keys( $replacements ), array_values( $replacements ), $file_path );
    $parsed_file_path = parse_url( $file_path );
    $remote_file      = true;

    // See if path needs an abspath prepended to work
    if ( file_exists( ABSPATH . $file_path ) ) {
        $remote_file = false;
        $file_path   = ABSPATH . $file_path;

    // Check if we have an absolute path
    } elseif ( ( ! isset( $parsed_file_path['scheme'] ) || ! in_array( $parsed_file_path['scheme'], array( 'http', 'https', 'ftp' ) ) ) && isset( $parsed_file_path['path'] ) && file_exists( $parsed_file_path['path'] ) ) {
        $remote_file = false;
        $file_path   = $parsed_file_path['path'];
    }

    return array(
        'remote_file' => $remote_file,
        'file_path'   => $file_path
    );
}

/**
 * Download a file using X-Sendfile, X-Lighttpd-Sendfile, or X-Accel-Redirect if available.
 * @param  string $file_path
 * @param  string $filename
 */
public static function download_file_xsendfile( $file_path, $filename ) {
    $parsed_file_path = self::parse_file_path( $file_path );

    if ( function_exists( 'apache_get_modules' ) && in_array( 'mod_xsendfile', apache_get_modules() ) ) {
        self::download_headers( $parsed_file_path['file_path'], $filename );
        header( "X-Sendfile: " . $parsed_file_path['file_path'] );
        exit;
    } elseif ( stristr( getenv( 'SERVER_SOFTWARE' ), 'lighttpd' ) ) {
        self::download_headers( $parsed_file_path['file_path'], $filename );
        header( "X-Lighttpd-Sendfile: " . $parsed_file_path['file_path'] );
        exit;
    } elseif ( stristr( getenv( 'SERVER_SOFTWARE' ), 'nginx' ) || stristr( getenv( 'SERVER_SOFTWARE' ), 'cherokee' ) ) {
        self::download_headers( $parsed_file_path['file_path'], $filename );
        $xsendfile_path = trim( preg_replace( '`^' . str_replace( '\\', '/', getcwd() ) . '`', '', $parsed_file_path['file_path'] ), '/' );
        header( "X-Accel-Redirect: /$xsendfile_path" );
        exit;
    }

    // Fallback
    self::download_file_force( $file_path, $filename );
}

/**
 * Force download - this is the default method.
 * @param  string $file_path
 * @param  string $filename
 */
public static function download_file_force( $file_path, $filename ) {
    $parsed_file_path = self::parse_file_path( $file_path );

    self::download_headers( $parsed_file_path['file_path'], $filename );

    if ( ! self::readfile_chunked( $parsed_file_path['file_path'] ) ) {
        if ( $parsed_file_path['remote_file'] ) {
            self::download_file_redirect( $file_path );
        } else {
            self::download_error( __( 'File not found', 'woocommerce' ) );
        }
    }

    exit;
}

/**
 * Get content type of a download.
 * @param  string $file_path
 * @return string
 * @access private
 */
private static function get_download_content_type( $file_path ) {
    $file_extension  = strtolower( substr( strrchr( $file_path, "." ), 1 ) );
    $ctype           = "application/force-download";

    foreach ( get_allowed_mime_types() as $mime => $type ) {
        $mimes = explode( '|', $mime );
        if ( in_array( $file_extension, $mimes ) ) {
            $ctype = $type;
            break;
        }
    }

    return $ctype;
}

/**
 * Set headers for the download.
 * @param  string $file_path
 * @param  string $filename
 * @access private
 */
private static function download_headers( $file_path, $filename ) {
    self::check_server_config();
    self::clean_buffers();
    nocache_headers();

    header( "X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow", true );
    header( "Content-Type: " . self::get_download_content_type( $file_path ) );
    header( "Content-Description: File Transfer" );
    header( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename . "\";" );
    header( "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" );

    if ( $size = @filesize( $file_path ) ) {
        header( "Content-Length: " . $size );
    }
}

/**
 * Check and set certain server config variables to ensure downloads work as intended.
 */
private static function check_server_config() {
    if ( function_exists( 'set_time_limit' ) && false === strpos( ini_get( 'disable_functions' ), 'set_time_limit' ) && ! ini_get( 'safe_mode' ) ) {
        @set_time_limit( 0 );
    }
    if ( function_exists( 'get_magic_quotes_runtime' ) && get_magic_quotes_runtime() && version_compare( phpversion(), '5.4', '<' ) ) {
        set_magic_quotes_runtime( 0 );
    }
    if ( function_exists( 'apache_setenv' ) ) {
        @apache_setenv( 'no-gzip', 1 );
    }
    @ini_set( 'zlib.output_compression', 'Off' );
    @session_write_close();
}

/**
 * Clean all output buffers.
 *
 * Can prevent errors, for example: transfer closed with 3 bytes remaining to read.
 *
 * @access private
 */
private static function clean_buffers() {
    if ( ob_get_level() ) {
        $levels = ob_get_level();
        for ( $i = 0; $i < $levels; $i++ ) {
            @ob_end_clean();
        }
    } else {
        @ob_end_clean();
    }
}

/**
 * readfile_chunked.
 *
 * Reads file in chunks so big downloads are possible without changing PHP.INI - http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Download_helper_for_large_files/.
 *
 * @param   string $file
 * @return  bool Success or fail
 */
public static function readfile_chunked( $file ) {
    $chunksize = 1024 * 1024;
    $handle    = @fopen( $file, 'r' );

    if ( false === $handle ) {
        return false;
    }

    while ( ! @feof( $handle ) ) {
        echo @fread( $handle, $chunksize );

        if ( ob_get_length() ) {
            ob_flush();
            flush();
        }
    }

    return @fclose( $handle );
}

/**
 * Filter headers for IE to fix issues over SSL.
 *
 * IE bug prevents download via SSL when Cache Control and Pragma no-cache headers set.
 *
 * @param array $headers
 * @return array
 */
public static function ie_nocache_headers_fix( $headers ) {
    if ( is_ssl() && ! empty( $GLOBALS['is_IE'] ) ) {
        $headers['Cache-Control'] = 'private';
        unset( $headers['Pragma'] );
    }
    return $headers;
}

/**
 * Die with an error message if the download fails.
 * @param  string $message
 * @param  string  $title
 * @param  integer $status
 * @access private
 */
private static function download_error( $message, $title = '', $status = 404 ) {
    if ( ! strstr( $message, '<a ' ) ) {
        $message .= ' <a href="' . esc_url( home_url() ) . '" class="wc-forward">' . __( 'Go to homepage', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>';
    }
    wp_die( $message, $title, array( 'response' => $status ) );
}
```

}

WC_Download_Handler::init();